# MATLAB's nonlinear regression

Tags: matlab, regression

I've recently been attempting a nonlinear regression in MATLAB and am unsure how to go about it.

I've attempted use of MATLAB's help pages and used [this](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/stats/fitnlm.html#bt1xncw-2) one

However, even if I just copy and paste the example (under "nonlinear model from matrix data")

I get this error:

```
Undefined function 'fitnlm' for input arguments of type 'function_handle'.
```

What I've tried is:

```
load carbig
X = [Horsepower,Weight];
y = MPG;
modelfun = @(b,x)b(1) + b(2)*x(:,1).^b(3) + b(4)*x(:,2).^b(5);
beta0 = [-50 500 -1 500 -1];
mdl = fitnlm(X,y,modelfun,beta0)
```

But it doesn't seem to like the `modelfun` part

I'm wondering why it has issues, if this is their example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think with my version of matlab `fitnlm` doesn't exist so I have to use [`NonLinearModel.fit`](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/stats/nonlinearmodel.fit.html)

Just tried it and it seems to work okay:

```
load carbig
X = [Horsepower,Weight];
y = MPG;
modelfun = @(b,x)b(1) + b(2)*x(:,1).^b(3) + b(4)*x(:,2).^b(5);
beta0 = [-50 500 -1 500 -1];
mdl = NonLinearModel.fit(X,y,modelfun,beta0)
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

You need to install Matlab's [`Statistics Toolbox`](http://www.mathworks.nl/products/statistics/) to use `fitnlm`. As it can be seen from the [list of functions](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/stats/functionlist.html) provided by the toolbox.
As you haven't installed it, it will not find the function on its path and therefore run into the above error.

`fitnlm` is introduced in matlab 2013b and statistics toolbox 8.3.

Comment: I can access other elements of the statistics toolbox, so I assumed they'd all work?

Comment: Which version of Matlab are you using?

Comment: 2012b, I have statistics toolbox 8.1 if that also helps?

Comment: Yeah, I added mine with an alternative function below